# Define bases and coordinates in arbitrary abstract vector spaces?

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, modules

I'm working on writing a program codifying some abstract algebra principles in order to teach myself some of the basics. I've worked through groups and rings and fields and the like, and these were all fairly straightforward.

I'm running into some issues with free modules and vector spaces however. A core part of both structures is the concept of a basis, so I assumed it may be useful to reason about coordinates in these spaces. An arbitrary vector can always be defined in terms of coordinates, but any coordinates only exist relative to some arbitrary basis vectors.

I'm not sure this recursive definition is feasible to implement; how can I square these two ideas? I can just define the basis as a set of elements, but then is there any way to reason about coordinates in that context? Do coordinates simply not neatly extend to abstract vector spaces?

When reasoning in any finite dimensional vector space, I can use the homomorphism to $F^n$, basically cheating my way out of it with the standard basis, but I want to support arbitrary vector spaces, including infinite ones.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, suppose you have an $n$-D vector space $V$ over the field $F$ with basis $\{b_1,\ldots,b_n\}$.

Then the mapping $f:V\rightarrow F^n$, where basis vector $v_i$ is mapped to the $i$th unit vector $e_i$, is a linear mapping (bijective and so an isomorphism) given
by $\sum_i a_iv_i\mapsto \sum_i a_ie_i$ and the image is the column vector $a=\left(\begin{array}{c} a_1\\\vdots\\a_n\end{array}\right)$.

So the $n$-tuple space $F^n$ can be viewed as a realization of the abstract space $V$.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Would you happen to know how this extends to infinite dimensional vector spaces?

Comment: In infinite dimensional vector spaces, a basis is an infinite set, say countable, such as in the polynomial ring K[x], in which each finite subset of the basis is linearly independent.